# Why acegi (Spring Security) converts password to uppercase before comparing?

Tags: java, spring-security

One of my colleague in QA team reported a bug to me, the bug said that can't change password to lowercase, otherwise login was rejected,using number or uppercase was all fine. The login system was implemented using acegi 1.0 (now called Spring Security).

This was a very strange bug,changing password is done by encrypting the user input string into MD5 string, I implemented this without using anything related acegi, I don't if the is the origin cause of the problem.

When the login is rejected, through debugging, I find that, the user input is converted into uppercase by acegi when passing to the acegi comparing logic. At first, I didn't believe this, when I checkout the acegi source and debugging with it, I find it does convert both username and password to uppercase ([source code line 121](http://www.acegisecurity.org/acegi-security/xref/org/acegisecurity/ui/webapp/SiteminderAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html)), Can you tell me  why it does this? This can cause password encoding mismatch!

Comment: are you using Siteminder? The code you linked to is an implementation specific to Siteminder. If you aren't using it you might be looking at the wrong code.

Comment: No, I checkout the source code from acegi, and looks exactly the same. This is ridiculous,why does it change the password to uppercase? I guess it must have a good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks matt, some guy in my team chose the Siteminder implementation of Acegi, which was the cause of this problem.